# Calculating the sum of every third column from many files

Tags: bash, awk

I have many files with three columns in a form of:

```
 file1 | file2

1 0 1  | 1 0 2

2 3 3  | 2 3 7

3 6 2  | 3 6 0

4 1 0  | 4 1 3

5 2 4  | 5 2 1
```

First two columns are the same in each file. I want to calculate a sum of 3 columns from every file to receive something like this:

```
1 0 3

2 3 10

3 6 2

4 1 3

5 2 5
```

For two files `awk 'FNR==NR { _a[FNR]=$3;} NR!=FNR { $3 += _a[FNR]; print;  }'  file*`
 work perfectly (I found this solution via google). How to change it on many files?

Comment: You already have it running for many files by having `file*`

Comment: Yes, but it works only fo 2 files in a way I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first two columns are same in each file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{b[FNR]=$1 FS $2;}{a[FNR]+=$3}END{for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){print b[i] FS a[i];}}' file*
```

Array `a` is used to have the cumulative sum of the 3rd column of all files.
Array `b` is used to the 1st and 2nd column values
In the end, we print the contents of array `a` and `b`

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Comment: `i<=length(a)` = `i<=FNR` and you should really be using OFS, not FS for the output field separator (`b[FNR]=$1 OFS $2 ... print b[i], a[i]`) and the trailing `;`s are redundant.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is:

```
awk '{sum[FNR]+=$3} ARGIND==(ARGC-1){print $1, $2, sum[FNR]}' file*
```

The above used GNU awk for ARGIND. With other awks just add `FNR==1{ARGIND++}` at the start.

Comment: `^1` cute approach, very elegant as always

Answer (score 1):

***file1***

```
$ cat f1
1 0 1 

2 3 3 

3 6 2 

4 1 0 

5 2 4
```

***file2***

```
$ cat f2
1 0 2

2 3 7

3 6 0

4 1 3

5 2 1
```

***Output***

```
$ awk -v start=3 'NF{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)a[FNR, i] = i>=start ? a[FNR, i]+$i  :  $i }END{ for(j=1; j<=FNR; j++){ s = "";  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){ s = (s ? s OFS:"")((j,i) in a ? a[j,i] : "") } print s }  }' f1 f2
1 0 3

2 3 10

3 6 2

4 1 3

5 2 5
```

***Better Readable***

variable `start` decides from which column start summing, suppose if you set 2 it will start summing from column2, column3 ...and so on, from all files, since you have equal no of fields and rows, it works well

```
awk -v start=3 '
              NF{
                   for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
                       a[FNR, i] = i>=start ? a[FNR, i]+$i : $i 
                }
             END{ 
                   for(j=1; j<=FNR; j++)
                   { 
                       s = "";  
                       for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
                       { 
                         s = (s ? s OFS:"")((j,i) in a ? a[j,i] : "") 
                       } 
                       print s 
                   }  
                }
               ' f1 f2
```